# How to find the size of a Collection using reflection in java?

Tags: java, reflection, collections

How do you find the size of a Collection (ie a `Set` or `List`) using reflection in java?

I have something like the example below and am wondering how to find the size of the collection while I'm using reflection.

**edit:**

```
Class<?> clazz = node.getClass();
Field [] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

for(Field field : fields) {
    System.out.println("declared fields:   "+ field.getType().getCanonicalName());

    //getting a generic type of a collection
    Type returntype = field.getGenericType();
    if (returntype instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) returntype;
        Type[] typeArguments = type.getActualTypeArguments();
        for(Type typeArgument : typeArguments) {
           Class<?> classType = (Class<?>) typeArgument;
           System.out.println("typeArgClass = " + classType.getCanonicalName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, how would it be done *without* reflection? (That is, what does reflection have to do with it...?)

Comment: Could you please provide a scenario of what do you mean by "find a size"? Is it as simple as calling a `size()` through reflection?

Comment: Could you give a short example?

Comment: And _why_ do you need to use reflection?

Comment: its required from me to use reflection

Comment: If this is homework it should be annotated accordingly.

Comment: Using reflection for this is, frankly, ridiculous and preposterous.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `node` is the collection instance.

```
int size;
try { 
  size = (Integer) node.getClass().getMethod("size").invoke(node);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Doesn't make much sense to do this via reflection when you just can call `node.size()`, though.

Comment: +1 because it *does* answer the question ... it *might* make more/some sense in a situation where the Type of object -- or many different unrelated Types, really -- was *not* derived from Collection (for whatever reason) but still had a `size()` method (in which case the above code wouldn't work, though). For just one "off Type" a cast would be more than sufficient...

Comment: Fixed the code to work for anything that has a size method returning an integer :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by using reflection. All classes that implement the `java.util.Collection` interface have the `size()` method that gives you the size of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The Scenario would be implementing a generic class that gives you a brief summary of the fields for an object and for the collection instance, you just want to spit out the size. 
I personally needed this to compare certain fields on two objects (o1 and o2) of the same type. I wanted to know if the collection instances have changed.

```
Field f1 = null;

   try {
f1 = o1.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
   }
...

if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(f1.getType())) { // Making sure it is of type Collection
   int v1Size = Collection.class.cast(v1).size();   //  This is what you need
```